# group values in an attribute in one dimension in SSAS

Tags: ssas

Could you tell me how can I group values in an attribute in one dimension in SSAS.
I one attribute one one dimension there are a lot of values and I want to group it according to some criteria How can I do it?
The Discretization” method is not working properly
thanks

Comment: Welcome, please have a look at this guide *[How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*. Improving your question will give you better answers. Have fun!

Comment: You can use your grouping criteria to create a hierarchy.